# how to retrieve the data from xmltype parameter returned from stored proc

Tags: oracle, ado.net, xmltype

I have a stored proc it returns xmltype parameter. How to get the data from that using vb.net?

```
db.Parameters("param", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.XmlType, _
                                           Data.ParameterDirection.Output)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used VB.net, but if you have the ability to change the stored procedure, I would consider converting the XMLTYPE to a CLOB and returning that instead (using xmltype.getclobval() ) I find it unlikely that the .net Oracle driver will provide support for XMLTYPE.

Obviously that will mean you need to make use of an XML parser in the VB code to parse the string (stored in the clob) to access any of the XML fields within it.